# How to Build Visual Studio Projects for Different Architectures

Tags: visual-studio-2010, batch-file, command-line, msbuild, buildconfiguration

I'm working on a batch script that will build projects made with Visual Studio 2010.  I need it to build four variations of the same project: 32-bit Debug, 32-bit Release, 64-bit Debug, and 64-bit Release.

So far, I think I've figured out how to build the project with it's last saved settings:

```
"%MSBUILD_DIR%\MSBuild.exe" !PROJECTNAME!.vcxproj /t:Build^
```

How can I modify this, so that it will build the four different configurations that I need?

Comment: In the long run you might be better of doing this in msbuild instead of in a batch file, as msbuild was made to perform tasks just like this (i.e. cross-product between configurations and platforms and then loop over it). Might end up shorter as well, plus you'll learn some msbuild which might come in handy in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set _project=project.vcxproj

call :do_build "%_project%" Release Win32
call :do_build "%_project%" Debug   Win32
call :do_build "%_project%" Release x64
call :do_build "%_project%" Debug   x64

endlocal
exit /b 0

:do_build
setlocal
set _proj=%~1
set _conf=%~2
set _arch=%~3
set _code=0
if "%_arch%"=="Win32" (set _vc_arg=x86) else (set _vc_arg=amd64)
call "%VS100COMNTOOLS%..\..\VC\vcvarsall.bat" %_vc_arg%
msbuild /t:build /p:Configuration="%_conf%" /p:Platform=%_arch% %_proj% || set "_code=1"
endlocal & exit /b %_code%
```

Comment: Where is `%_arch%` set, and what does the call to `vcvarsall.bat` do?

Comment: From what I can tell it looks like `%_arch%` is intended to be representative of the native platform architecture on which the compiler is being run.  Is that correct? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4d2c09s(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Sorry. Originally I used slightly different script. See update.

Comment: Thanks!  Do you know if there is a way to specify the build output folder for MSBuild?

Comment: If you  mean you want to redefine `$(OutDir)` or `$(IntDir)` - try `/p:OutDir="..."`.